# How to remove mapping/binding of application in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have some AppleScript which I run via osascript on the command line.

The script itself looks like:

```
on run argv
    set appname to item 1 of argv
    set tmp to item 2 of argv
    set jsfl_path to POSIX file tmp

    if application appname is running then
        tell application appname
            with timeout of 600 seconds
                open jsfl_path
            end timeout
        end tell
    end if
end run
```

I updated Adobe CC Animate to the latest version. I was previously running the 2018 version. It turns out they renamed the file pattern. It used to be Adobe Animate CC 2018. Now it is Adobe Animate 2019.

Here is where the problem starts. In my script I was sloppy and change the name to Adobe Animate CC 2019.

When I ran the AppleScript, it produced a dialog to Choose Application. In my haste, I accidentally mapped it to the wrong program.

[image]

I'd like to remove this mapping. What I cannot find is where this mapping is stored. Does anyone know where this type of mapping gets saved?

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t really stored anywhere, the Script Editor uses your declarations to determine where to load the scripting terminology from.  Recompiling the script after making an edit should reset things, otherwise you can restart the Script Editor.  Note that you need to use a specific bundle identifier or application name - using a variable to specify the application can be problematic, as the terminology is loaded at compile time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I run this command line so the Script Editor, as far as I know, isn't in use. Or is it? Sorry for sounding dense. I didn't even know it was "compiled".

Comment: Also as an FYI, I did make a mod to the script, essentially just added a dialog. When run it still seems to try and call the other incorrectly mapped app. In this case, that app is Illustrator. I can tell because if I have Illustrator opened, it causes it to do things. It would imply to me there is some saved mapping.

Comment: Scripts are compiled to byte code (by the Script Editor, or `osacompile` on the fly if using something like text or a heredoc), using the declarations in the script.  If you are using a variable for the application, the particular app terminology will not being used (since the app isn't declared at compile time), so any results will most likely be accidental - try using a specific bundle identifier.

Comment: Interesting. Where does osacompile cache things? I did find an AppleScript preference file that contained ApplicationMapping. I removed the entry, but the problem still exists. I suppose I may need to reboot which I'll try later.